# How to prevent multiple canceled HTTP requests while seeking in videojs?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

When I seek the video using the mouse by clicking on the progress bar then holding and moving forward or backward, the browser makes multiple requests and cancels it immediately like the image below. It makes the server high load.

How can I prevent that?

[image: Seeking]

I test at https://videojs.com/advanced/?video=disneys-oceans